# Real roots plot of the modified bessel function

Tags: numerical-methods, special-functions, roots

Could anyone point me a program so i can calculate the roots of

$$ K_{ia}(2 \pi)=0 $$

here $ K_{ia}(x) $ is the modified Bessel function of second kind with (pure complex)index 'k' :D

My conjecture of exponential potential means that the solutions are $ s=2a $ with

$$ \zeta (1/2+is)=0. $$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used the free pari/gp $(*)$ to get the smallest positive solutions :
\begin{array} {l}
9.76877008350997786701461088004548816694073504626\\
12.4484878927757792253076746584484174280206806290\\
14.6849597759503320940392747073070219296666773881\\
16.6915789382924172031614835847470262244558902255\\
18.5493751970112696445359821473043722645995430537\\
20.2999030639074716000431186500336768257041209063\\
21.9679863621154849828379155738628510793020013525\\
23.5699217186674186162756939876181463960995601839\\
25.1171217228471128822167760437525949613439934666\\
26.6179647161774511589115811996122442026801440680\\
28.0788271377389792376836682977823877359218232495\\
29.5047018750550818302335792765863272958843396063\\
\end{array}

These solutions are much more regular than the zeta zeros as you may appreciate in this plot of $\;\displaystyle x\mapsto \operatorname{K}_{ix}(2\pi)\;e^{\pi\,x/2}\sqrt{x}\;$ (the oscillations became quickly very small thus the 'rescaling') :

[image: K_ix(2 pi)]

Concerning the relations between the $\zeta\left(\frac 12+ix\right)$ zeros and the $\operatorname{K}_{ix}(2\pi)$ zeros a quick search gave the paper by Fredrik Strömberg ["On the zeros of linear combinations of K-Bessel functions"](http://www2.math.uu.se/research/pub/Stromberg.pdf) with the following theorem :

The functions
\begin{align}
F_1(t)&=4\pi^2\left[\operatorname{K}_{\frac 94+\frac{it}2}(2\pi)+\operatorname{K}_{\frac 94-\frac{it}2}(2\pi)\right]\\
F_2(t)&=F_1(t)-6\pi\left[\operatorname{K}_{\frac 54+\frac{it}2}(2\pi)+\operatorname{K}_{\frac 54-\frac{it}2}(2\pi)\right]\\
\end{align}
have a total number of zeros in $\{0<\Re(t)\le T\}$ equal to
$$N(T)=\frac{T}{2\pi}\log\left(\frac T{2\pi e}\right)+O(\log T),$$
exactly as for $\xi\left(\frac 12+ix\right)$ (and thus $\zeta\left(\frac 12+ix\right)$). Furthermore all of their zeros are located along the real axis.

The function $\xi$ is defined by $\;\displaystyle \xi(s):=\frac 12s(s-1)\pi^{-\frac s2}\Gamma\left(\frac s2\right)\zeta\left(s\right)$
and has the same complex zeros as $\zeta$ but a simpler [functional equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#The_functional_equation) : $\xi(s)=\xi(1-s)$.

In fact Hejhal (following Polya's $1926$ work "Bemerkung über die Integraldarstellung der Riemannschen $\xi$-Funktion") studied the approximant :
\begin{align}
\xi^*_N\left(\frac 12+it\right)=&\sum_{n=1}^N 4\pi^2\,n^4\left[\operatorname{K}_{\frac 94+\frac{it}2}(2\pi n^2)+\operatorname{K}_{\frac 94-\frac{it}2}(2\pi n^2)\right]\\-&\sum_{n=1}^N 6\pi\,n^2\left[\operatorname{K}_{\frac 54+\frac{it}2}(2\pi n^2)+\operatorname{K}_{\frac 54-\frac{it}2}(2\pi n^2)\right]\\
\end{align}

Strömberg adds "Since the approximations are at best loose, one does not seriously propose this as a means of reaching the RH". I don't include the curve(s) obtained because the zeros are rather different (a similar repartition doesn't require the same zeros...) (of course I could too have made a stupid mistake!).

These results and references should be of interest (if you don't already know them) as well as this [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0801.2996) from George Gasper and [this](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2002-130-06/S0002-9939-01-06351-1/S0002-9939-01-06351-1.pdf) and [this one](http://www.math.byu.edu/~cardon/papers/simple_zeros.pdf) by David Cardon.
$$-$$
$(*)$ [pari/gp](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/download.html)'s script for the first root :

> solve(x=9,10,real(besselk(I*x,2*Pi)))

Comment: OK thanks in fact i managed to prove that the roots of the function (smooth part) was about $ \frac{ \sqrt{E}}{2\pi}log(\frac{\sqrt{E}}{2\pi e}) $ that's why i thought that the zeros would be related

Comment: @Jose: I added more references. Fine continuation !

Answer (score 5):

I can quantify somewhat Raymond's suggestion that the zeros of $K_{ia}(2\pi)$ are much more regular than the zeros of $\zeta(1/2+i2a)$.  The calculations below are rough and I didn't verify the details, so this is perhaps more of a comment than an answer.

The Bessel function in question has the integral representation

$$
K_{ia}(2\pi) = \int_0^\infty e^{-2\pi \cosh t} \cos(at)\,dt.
$$

Naively applying the saddle point method to this integral indicates that, for large $a$,

$$
\begin{align}
K_{ia}(2\pi) &\approx \frac{e^{-a\pi/2} \sqrt{\pi}}{(a^2-4\pi^2)^{1/4}} \Bigl( \sin f(a) + \cos f(a) \Bigr) \\
&=\frac{e^{-a\pi/2} \sqrt{2\pi}}{(a^2-4\pi^2)^{1/4}} \cos\left( f(a) - \frac{\pi}{4} \right),
\end{align}
$$

where

$$
f(a) = \frac{a}{2} \log\left(\frac{a^2-2\pi^2+a\sqrt{a^2-4\pi^2}}{2\pi^2}\right) - \sqrt{a^2-4\pi^2}.
$$

Here's a plot of $K_{ia}(2\pi)$ in blue versus this approximation in red (both scaled by a factor of $e^{a\pi/2}\sqrt{a}$ as in Raymond's graph).

[image]

The approximation has zeros whenever

$$
f(a) = \frac{3\pi}{4} + n\pi, \tag{$*$}
$$

and since

$$
f(a) \approx a\log(a/\pi) - a
$$

for large $a$ we expect that solutions of $(*)$ for large $n$ satisfy

$$
a \approx \frac{3\pi/4+n\pi}{W\Bigl((3\pi/4+n\pi)/e\Bigr)},
$$

where $W$ is the Lambert W function.

Here's a plot of $e^{a\pi/2} \sqrt{a} K_{ia}(2\pi)$ in blue with these approximate zeros in red.

[image]

Comment: Nice asymptotic expansion Antonio! From your result we get too a ![nicer picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/GAHYS.png) (with just a fictive additional zero at $2\pi$). Thanks to share!

Comment: A small amendment: if we let $$\alpha(x) = \frac{3\pi/4+x\pi}{W\Bigl((3\pi/4+x\pi)/e\Bigr)}$$ be the asymptotic for the zeros of $K_{ia}(2\pi)$ obtained in this answer, then the the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/921987/5531) indicate that the $n^\text{th}$ zeta zero $z_n$ has the asymptotic asymptotic to $$z_n \sim 2\pi \alpha\!\left(\frac{n-3\pi/4}{\pi}\right).$$

Comment: For the $n$-th zeta zero I obtained (numerically) [excellent results](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2400635/riemann-hypothesis-numeric-verification-question#comment4956303_2400635) using $$t_n\approx 2\pi\,\exp(W((n-11/8)/e)+1)$$ This is also $\;t_n\approx 2\pi\dfrac{n-11/8}{W((n-11/8)/e)}$.