# Asymptotics for zeta zeros?

Tags: riemann-zeta

What are the best known asymptotics for the nth zeta zero (imaginary part)? Is there anything similar to $p_n\sim n\log n$, ie where $\rho$ is in form $\sigma+it$, $t_n\sim\dots?$

Comment: Guilherme França, André LeClair: http://i.stack.imgur.com/CmZmV.png

Comment: Table[N[InverseFunction[RiemannSiegelTheta][Pi*(n - 1/2)], 30], {n, 0,
   12}]

Comment: Related [thread1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3929630/if-z-n-are-the-zeros-of-the-zeta-function-what-is-the-limit-of-imz-n-a?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [thread2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3821831/improving-an-approximation-for-the-inverse-of-the-riemann-siegel-θ-function/3822898)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may check following paper:

[A theory for the zeros of Riemann Zeta and other L-functions](http://arxiv.org/abs/1407.4358) by Guilherme França, André LeClair

Answer (score 7):

Yes, $\gamma_n\sim2\pi n/\log(n)$.  This is in Titchmarsh, for example.

For a better asymptotic, write the number of zeros to height $T$ as
$$
N(T)\sim \frac{T}{2\pi}\log\left(\frac{T}{2\pi}\right)-\frac{T}{2\pi}.
$$
(The error term in this asymptotic is $O(\log(T))$.)  We want to invert the relationship
$$
n \sim \frac{\gamma_n}{2\pi}\log\left(\frac{\gamma_n}{2\pi}\right)-\frac{\gamma_n}{2\pi}.
$$
Mathematica tells me that
$$
\gamma_n\sim \frac{2\pi n}{W(n/e)},
$$
where $W(z)$ is the Lambert function, which inverts $z=w\exp(w)$.  ($W(z)$ is called ProductLog in Mathematica)

A better asymptotic would require a better one for $N(T)$, which depends subtly on $S(T)$, the argument of the Riemann zeta function.

Comment: Where does Titchmarsh’s asymptotic expression come from?

Comment: @Partey5 The Argument Principle in complex analysis, the functional equation for the zeta function, and Stirling's formula asymptotic for the Gamma function which appears in the functional equation.

Comment: Is there a paper where he explains this?