# At what hight is the nth zero Riemann zeta function?

Tags: riemann-zeta

At what hight is the nth zero Riemann zeta function?

It is a mathematical formula but I can not get under it on the Internet (once I found).

Comment: Duplicated: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/921987/asymptotics-for-zeta-zeros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is known that $N(T)$, the number of zeros of the Riemann zeta-function above the real axis with imaginary part (height) at most $T$ has the asymptotic formula
$$
N(T) \sim \frac T{2\pi} \log \frac T{2\pi e}.
$$
(The error term is very good, namely $O(\log T)$, and can be made explicit if needed.) It follows that the height of the $n$th zero is asymptotically $2\pi n/\log n$; more precisely, it is
$$
\sim \frac{2\pi n}{\log n} \bigg( 1 + \frac{\log\log n+1}{\log n} \bigg)
$$
(although here the error term isn't as good as in the first formula).

Comment: Something, however, with the first Fomule probably wrong. For N(1) = -0.45118513581289504; for N(10) = -0.8470652798318857

Comment: Ahh... ok, my mistake ;)