# Data analysis with the Riemann zeta function zeros

Tags: roots, riemann-zeta

Plotting the Riemann zeta zeros (the imaginary part) then it seems like they follow a pattern:
Let $z_1,\cdots,z_n$ be real numbers such that $z_i < z_j$ for $i<j$ and $\zeta(z_j \cdot I + 1/2 ) = 0$. Then it seems like there exists sequences $a_k,b_k$ of real numbers such that:
$$ z_j = \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k \cdot j^{b_k}$$

I have done some analysis in R:

Let z denote the first say 2000 "zeros" of $\zeta$ in R. Let x denote the sequence 1:length(z). Then:

```
  source("zeros.R")
  x <- seq(1:length(z))
  m <- nls(z ~ a1*I(x^b1)+a2*I(x^b2)+a3*I(x^b3),start=list(a3=6,b3=0.8,a1=1,b1=0.5,a2=3,b2=0.1),trace=T,control=list(maxiter=1000,minFactor=10^-5))
  M <- matrix(c(m$m$predict(x),z),ncol=2,byrow=F)
  print( head(M))
```

We get $(Z_j, z_j)$ where $Z_j$ denotes the prediction of the model:

```
         [,1]     [,2]

 [1,] 14.72366 14.13473

 [2,] 20.60379 21.02204

 [3,] 25.39784 25.01086

 [4,] 29.63939 30.42488

 [5,] 33.52986 32.93506

 [6,] 37.17123 37.58618

 [7,] 40.62363 40.91872

 [8,] 43.92607 43.32707

 [9,] 47.10558 48.00515

[10,] 50.18180 49.77383

[11,] 53.16956 52.97032

[12,] 56.08039 56.44625

[13,] 58.92345 59.34704

[14,] 61.70618 60.83178

[15,] 64.43472 65.11254

[16,] 67.11422 67.07981

[17,] 69.74901 69.54640

[18,] 72.34283 72.06716

[19,] 74.89890 75.70469

[20,] 77.42003 77.14484
```

which is not that bad I would say. 
Is there any known result in this direction?

You can find the zeros.R [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VP4GcUEV65qzs7uSV7VaWBz4vCogPKbc/view?usp=sharing).

[image: $z_j-Z_j$]

The above observation should heuristically follow from this observation which is based on data:

There exists a $K_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for each $K \ge K_0$ there exist real numbers $a_{K,1}, a_{K,2},\cdots,a_{K,K},b_{K,1}, b_{K,2},\cdots,b_{K,K}$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have:

$$ z_n = \epsilon_K+\sum_{k=1}^K a_{K,k} n^{b_{K,k}}$$
$$ \epsilon_K \equiv N(0,\sigma_K^2)$$
$$ \lim_{K \rightarrow \infty} \sigma_K = 0$$

Then taking the limit $K \rightarrow \infty$ we should heuristically get $\lim_{K \rightarrow \epsilon} \epsilon_K = 0$, since the expectation of $\epsilon_K$ is $=0$ and the variance of $\epsilon_K$ goes in the limit to $0$, and hence heuristically the above stated infinite sum should be true.

I have computed with the code above example values for $K=1,2,3$ using the nls function in R. It would be nice, if someone knows another package in R or Python to estimate the $a_k,b_k$ if he or she tells me of that package, since with nls I don't think one can do more than 6 parameters (K=3), or at least I haven't figured out how, if it is possible.

Comment: I think you mean, the "imaginary part" (of the nontrivial zeros), as the real part is conjecturally 1/2.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I will edit the question.

Comment: Can you give us the full R program ? (R! my favourite language).

Comment: Could you produce a plot of $z_i-Z_i$ for $i$ up to at least a few hundred? Keeping your optimization fixed to the first three terms of your series expansion.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit: I have put a link for the zeros.R. The program in R is given above.

Answer (score 1):

Heuristically this cannot be true if the sum is finite. In particular it is well known that $z_n\approx 2\pi n/\log(n)$, whereas any finite sum above will ultimately grow like $j^B$, where $B=\max_i b_i$.

It is however interesting that this seems to work locally beyond just a few terms, so feel free to post some plots of $z_i-Z_i$ to study this further.

Comment: I added some plot.

Comment: Do you know a reference for $ z_n \equiv 2\pi n / \log(n)$?

Comment: @stackExchangeUser https://math.stackexchange.com/q/921987/5531

Comment: @AntonioVargas: Thank you for the reference.